# SQL Server 2017 stand-alone stuck

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2017

My standalone install of SQL Server 2017 is stuck on the Feature Selection page. Below is what I see in the install logs, does anyone have any ideas how to get past this?

> (08) 2017-10-24 11:15:20 Slp: Running Action:
>   SetMultiInstanceTransformAction (08) 2017-10-24 11:15:20 Slp: Error:
>   Action
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.SetMultiInstanceTransformAction"
>   threw an exception during execution. (08) 2017-10-24 11:15:20 Slp:
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionExecutionException:
>   Value cannot be null. (08) 2017-10-24 11:15:20 Slp: Parameter name:
>   Cannot find SqlDiscoveryData in Datastore --->
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (08) 2017-10-24
>   11:15:20 Slp: Parameter name: Cannot find SqlDiscoveryData in
>   Datastore (08) 2017-10-24 11:15:20 Slp:    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.QueryPackageTransforms.set_DatastoreDiscoveryData

Comment: What is OS version on which you are trying to install SQL Server 2017. Can you post complete output on shared drive and post link here. Also refer to this [MSDN Thread about computer name being too long](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c0224025-409b-406d-a29d-366c7e0679a3/sql-server-2012-standalone-setup?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade)

Comment: Ahem... Have you tried... Restarting it?

Comment: Here is a link to the full detail.txt file - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1us18oL7bJz3DJlqvN8WBkmFYVjR4jykdHaz2kdAMU2E/edit?usp=sharing
We are on Server 2012 R2 Standard. Name is only 10 characters long.

Hey Eric, we've rebooted this thing about 4 times.  Trying to setup an HA environment and this is the second server.  First one went through no problems, only difference is the name of server 2.  It's just one number that's different.

Comment: How are you getting the install media to that server? Looks like the media might be having issues when it's looking for the datastore xml. Try a fresh copy to that server, locally.

Comment: There are lot of messages saying like `'H:\x64\setup\x64\sql_engine_core_shared.msi'` not found. This may well be because the installation is missing these files. I hope you are not installing from shared drive

Comment: Hi Shanky, I checked the media (H drive) and the file does indeed exist.  It's a ISO I downloaded from MSDN.  It worked fine on server A.  Copied file over to server B and this stuckness happens.